# NuGet in Package Manager Console installs old version of package by default

Tags: nuget

We have an internal NuGet repository for Our class Libraries. I've created a package MyPackage Version 1.0.0.0 which had a bug, so I pushed a New Version (or revision) of the package, 1.0.0.1.

Now, when I create a New Project and use the Manage NuGet Packages dialog, I get the latest Version (1.0.0.1) when I install the package. However, when I use the Package Manager Console for another New Project and type Install-Package MyPackage, I get Version 1.0.0.0 by default.

Why does this happen? I can't find anything in the NuGet documentation explaining why this happens, so it seems to be a bug in NuGet.exe.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue and the below fix did not help - I deleted the cached versions, then did "install", still got the old version.

However running update does update the package to the latest version. Anyone got a solution to this?

Comment: I've raised an issue on the Nuget codeplex here: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3747

Upvote it so someone fixes the bug!

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted it. I'm not in the position to try the solution suggested below right now, but from the issue linked to from your issue at CodePlex, it seems to be a bug in NuGet right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For information if anyone runs across this issue, it was a bug in 2.7 that has been fixed as of 2.8. Details at: https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/3684

Upgrading your client to 2.8 will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the Update-Package command.

The package is probably "cached" locally, and when you use the "Install", it only gets the cached version.

You can also verify this by going to:

(windows)

```
C:\Users\~MyUserName~\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache\
```

OR (linux)

```
/Users/MyUserName/.nuget/packages/
```

(Replace ~MyUserName~ of course)

and deleting the package from there...then "Install".
(The idea being, if its not in the cache, it'll go back to the server to get it)

Comment: Fraid this doesn't work for me - I deleted all the packages from my cache, then did install-package on one of our private packages, got an old version. Running update-package afterwards gives the latest version, but install-package should give the latest version in the first place. It works against nuget.org but not our private server :(

Comment: //install-package should give the latest version in the first place//  ......   That is one of those "d@mned if you do, d@mned if you don't" scenarios for the original developers.  That is why the "update package" exists......to move to a later version.  So I was off about the cache part, but somewhere it "remembers" what the installed version way.      With my little understanding of all the scenarios, I could side with your understanding, but probably (somewhere) there is a scenario where that could screw the end-developer.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it seems like 90% of the time when you're installing a package, you want the newest version. If you want an older version you've got the -version flag to choose a specific older version. 

Either way, it makes no sense that running the command against nuget.org gives the latest version, yet running the command against our local server doesn't.

Comment: This answer is not receiving enough love. I had the same issue with the Artifacts repo in Devops: The UI and nuget list showed me a recently updated package but "nuget install" always installed the previous version. Deleting the cache solved the issue for me immediately.